# How to build a software for Windows Embedded CE6.0 R3

Tags: sdk, windows-ce

I am trying to build a Software for Windows® Embedded CE6.0 R3. But I couldn't figure out how to manage this?

- I couldn't find something like an SDK
- I don't know which Visual Studio I should choose. (Sometimes I read about VS2005 sometimes 2008)
- I think I misunderstood something really generally about this Operation System

Do someone know a good source for resources about Windows® Embedded CE6.0 R3. I just Need Information how to start, and what is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows CE is a modular OS, meaning that an OEM has very wide latitude in what may or may not be available in the OS. Because of this, there is no way to have a general "standard" SDK for devices.  You could end up building an app against features that don't exist on the target, or you might now have API access to features that do exist.  At least that's the argument that Microsoft gives.

My experience (and it's fairly deep) is that if you build an SDK for the same processor as your target and just throw in everything in the OS catalog, it allows you to develop apps for anything.  You have to be aware of what your target hardware doesn't support and be somewhat careful to avoid using those features, but it's not that difficult. For example, I've been using one single SDK for probably 5 years and have never had a problem or reason to change.

So, in general, you just need to get an SDK for the same processor.  Checking with your device vendor is a good start, but if you find one from another vendor, as long as the processors match, you're probably fine.

As for the version of Studio, it depends on what you're doing.  If you are creating the OS itself, you need Studio 2005.  If you are only creating applications to run on the OS, you can use Studio 2005 or Studio 2008.